# Using Serial Queries with TanStack query to avoid API timeout

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am building a `React` project using `TanStack Query` that requires me to make three different query requests to the `Codeforces API` to fetch some data for the user.

If the queries are called `Q1`, `Q2` and `Q3`, I need to ensure `Q2` is only called `2` seconds after calling `Q1`, and `Q3` is only called `4` seconds after calling `Q1` due avoid the rate limit of `1 request per 2 seconds` by the API.

Is there a way to do so conveniently? Maybe something analogous to the `useQueries()` function in `TanStack`, but for serial queries that need to be executed after a time delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing yet, but there is a discussion going on about [useSequentialQueries](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/4727).

If you don't need data cached separately, you can just make one query that executes multiple requests:

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const result = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['my', 'key'],
  queryFn: async () => {
    const q1 = await fetchQ1()
    await sleep(2000)
    const q2 = await fetchQ2(q1)
    await sleep(2000)
    return fetchQ3(q2)
  }
})
```